# Rest api dedicated fields vs free text forms

Tags: rest

What are the pros and cons of using explicit json keys for fields instead of embedding them into a text field?

example:

1.dedicated fields:

```
{name:joe, age:35, job:teacher, hobby:soccer,city:London,isMarried:true}
```

schema: name:string,age:int,job:string,hobby:string,city:string,isMarried:bool

2.free text form

```
{name:joe, age:35, details:"job:teacher, hobby:soccer,city:London,isMarried:true"}
```

schema: name:string, age:int, details: string

What I think of:
pros of 1:

- easier to parse
- easier to set constraints on fields

pros of 2:

- no need to change the api in case of change in the fields

any other reason to use the 1st or 2nd?